# Not returning a refund for a car purchase

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, small-claims-court, refund

Imagine someone pays a deposit for an out of state “classic” car, with an agreement that the balance would be payable when the car is collected - although no time frame was agreed between the two parties.

Suppose the seller then decides not to sell the car as he got a better offer from someone else after the initial agreement was made, and states he would return the deposit but has failed to do so.

What are the legal aspects the purchaser might wish to consider to get their deposit back?

Comment: Could be a case of renegotiating a contract, adherence to a contract, or even fraud, depending on the intent of the prospective seller of the car, and whatever the contract (verbal or written form) stipulates.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the legal aspects the purchaser might wish to consider to get
> their deposit back?

You demand a return of the deposit, and if it doesn't happen, you sue them if it is cost effective to do so (assuming that deposit was not made via credit card; if it was you may be able to reverse the charge).

Comment: credit card or similar payment method: Paypal for example supports chargeback for cases of fraud or non-delivery.

Comment: @Trish Good point.